# How to connect TB to a external broker mqtt?

Tags: mqtt, thingsboard

I change configuration files but when I want to publish a message, I get this error :

> Blockquote

```
 Property: gateway.connection.security
    Value: accessToken:dRPsN8Jgc5pbunFkVeah
    Reason: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.thingsboard.gateway.service.MqttGatewaySecurityConfiguration' for property 'security'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.thingsboard.gateway.service.MqttGatewaySecurityConfiguration' for property 'security': no matching editors or conversion strategy found


Action:

Update your application's configuration
```

Comment: It would probably help if you edited the question to include changes you have made to the configuration files.

Comment: yes, please post an actual part of configuration file you have changed